# In R, how can I reproduce and increase paired values in a vector?

Tags: r, vector, repeat

In R, I need to create a vector in which the values appear in order, starting with 1, in which each value is duplicated once, as shown below:
`v <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)` and so on.

The above vector has five pairs, but the number of pairs can be many more.

How can I do that without having to manually type every pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

```
rep(1:10, each = 2)

[1]  1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  5  5  6  6  7  7  8  8  9  9 10 10
```